# Xvnc with XRENDER

Tags: vnc, x-windows, x-server, rendering

Looking for Xvnc that has the RENDER extensions enabled. Only one i've found is the realvnc's one, but i'm unable to compile.

I'm working on ubuntu jaunty amd64.

Comment: what's preventing you from compiling it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really not a lot of options out there.  You might consider using [NX technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology) instead of VNC -- see [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/), [NeatX](http://code.google.com/p/neatx/), and [OpenNX](http://opennx.sourceforge.net/) for open source versions, or [NoMachine](http://www.nomachine.com/) for a commercial version.

Here's the status of all VNC servers I know about:

- [RealVNC Free version](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/index.html).  Fix your compile issues, and reconstruct the [patch from this 2006 report](http://www.realvnc.com/pipermail/vnc-list/2006-February/054031.html) that allowed Xvnc + XRENDER to work.  The patch link seems to be dead, but reconstructing the patch from his sources may be possible.
- [RealVNC Enterprise Edition](http://www.realvnc.com/products/enterprise/) supports XRENDER [in v4.5](http://www.realvnc.com/products/enterprise/4.5/release-notes.html).  Unfortunately, the only supported Ubuntu versions are the LTS versions and 7.10-8.10.  If you are willing to buy a license key, I'd contact support and see if they have a beta build for Ubuntu 9.04.
- [xf4vnc](http://xf4vnc.sourceforge.net/news.html) claims XRENDER support.  There's no package for it, and it's been around a while, but it seems to still have [some activity](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xf4vnc/).  It seems to [require modifications to XFree86 drivers](http://lists.debian.org/debian-wnpp/2003/02/msg00102.html), which is why there's no Debian/Ubuntu package.  But you may be able to compile and install locally.

These provide a VNC server module to an existing Xserver.  As such, if you can configure an underlying Xserver with Xrender support, you might be able to use one of these.

- Vino, GNOME's builtin VNC server, [seems to](http://blog.workaround.org/2009/09/vino-compiz-optimism/).
- krfbb, KDE's version.
- x11vnc, a VNC server not tied to any desktop environment.

The following VNC Xservers do not provide XRENDER support insofar as I can tell:

- TightVNC

Comment: Thanks for the reply; i was already using neatx, works fine but my project requires to have a 'web' display, so vnc is the only solution i've found so far.

RealVNC Entreprise edition is working fine; but i don't know if we could afford to pay $50 for each instance of running server.

RealVNC free edition seems to be the best solution so far; but i doubt i can have the skills to compile it from scratch.

Comment: I don't know if you could help me for this, i'd be pleased to reward you if you could provide me with a compiled version of the realvnc with xrender support.

Would you be interested in that project ?

Comment: no.  (15 chars.)